# ValueError at /user_settings/ ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: django

I'm creating a user setting page , where user can update his/her profile but after creating a ModelForm is gives this error.
ModelForm has no model class specified.

code in forms

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from blog.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Mata:
        model=customer
        fields= '__all__'
        exclude=['user']
```

Code in views

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def user_settings(request):
    users=request.user.customer
    form=UserForm(instance=users)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form=UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=users)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blog/account_settings.html', context)
```

Comment: It is `Meta`, not `Mata`.

Comment: Thanks Man..Thats helped me

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is with your spellings

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=customer
```

I once wrote **meta** instead of **Meta** and spent a good 2 hours to figure Meta is case-sensitive too (atleast solved my error)